# Project to track on screen object - Unsure how to go about it

Tags: c#, vb.net

I've started learning c# and vb.net and have a project related to tracking a moving object on the screen to help me learn some basics.

In essence, I will have a ball on the screen which moves from left to right (only horizontally), and when it reaches a certain point (e.g. 250 pixels from the "mid" point either side) I need to know this, and click an on-screen counter to increase a value (or decrease depending on left or right) and reset the ball to the centre (note that the ball speed will vary from incredible slow to an instant "jump").

I've been asked to look into c# and vb and decide which is best, then use it to create the program. As a complete newbie in both of these, does anyone have a recommendation and a starting point please?
My background is Javascript, HTML and very basic Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you define as a "Starting Point" do you mean like different C# libs to use etc. If all you are trying to do is move a ball from left to right basically and count the difference it would be so simple to do in C# XNA.

You can also do it in windows forms too which I really thing shouldn't be too hard at all. Obviously you would create the velocity formulas yourself I don't believe that's what you're asking.

One way to get the screen size in windows forms is:

```
public Rectangle GetScreen()
{
    return Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
}
```

This will return a rectangle with a width and height that you can call, divide both values by 2 and it will give you the center of the screen. Then just add a method that is called every frame to check the balls value from the middle of the screen.

From what I've read I understand what you want to do, but I'm unsure if you just want a windows form or if you'd prefer to use a small game engine like XNA etc.

Either way best of luck and let me know :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. In essence, we will run an application which is monitoring a network. This application has a ball which moves side to side when (simply put) latency changes. When it changes too much I need to click the left or right button in the application to reset it (and count). This needs to be done using an external program which monitors the ball (as it is going to be reused for similar scenarios) and it needs to be written in either vb.net or c#. I'll have a read of C# XNA now. Note that the "middle" refers to the line the ball the moves along, not of the screen. Thanks.

Comment: As I've never worked with either C# (or C# XNA) or Windows Forms, I don't really have a preference. I originally did this really simply using AutoHotKey to determine the location of the ball by it's color, but not only was it quite inaccurate when the ball moved too fast past the pixel border, it wasn't what I was required to do (which was to use c# or vb.net)

Comment: Oh Ok I understand a bit better now. You are basically looking for a visual representation of latency in a sense. I dont think XNA would be the best for it if you are planning on adding some form of Networking, I would use forms and a really good tool to use would be the chart system they have or something along those lines, that way you could actually use the real values from latency instead of trying to convert them to moving the ball a certain amount of pixels if that was your original intention. I would just start with the basics getting a latency pulse from something and mapping it.

Comment: The app itself is already developed (the ball is needed for various reasons), this is just a task to handle parts of it externally. The ball itself is more a bar where we have an acceptable latency range, but if it drops to 0 the connection is dropped, and if it goes past X it needs resetting